# How do I replace part of string using regexp?

Tags: regex, perl, string, replace

HI, 
I have a string that looks like

```
/dir/dir1/filename.txt
```

I want to replace the "filename.txt" with some other name leaving the "/dir/dir1" intact 
so after the replace the string would look like

```
/dir/dir1/newfilename.txt
```

how would I do that using RegExp in Perl considering that I don't know the value of "filename"

Many Thanks

P.S : "filename.txt" and "newfilename.txt" have been used for the purpose of making things simple when asking the question the original filename will vary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$filename =~ s%/[^/]*$%/newfilename.txt%;
```

- `s%...%...%` - use `%` as the delimiter, so you can use `/` in the pattern
- `/` - match a slash
- `[^/]*` - and any string not containing a slash
- `$` - up to the end of the string

Comment: @Alnitak Thank you very much for your reply, one more thing please, if I just wanted to extract "filename.txt" from "/dir/dir1/filename.txt" instead of replacing it, what would I use in the regexp

Comment: use "if ($filename =~ m%...%)" and wrap the original [^/]* bit with brackets { i.e. ([^/]*) } and then it'll be available as $1

Answer (score 11):

I would suggest against using regular expressions to fiddle with filenames/paths. Directory Separators, valid/invalid characters vary from one platform to the next and can be a problem to hunt down. I advise you try [File::Spec](http://search.cpan.org/~smueller/PathTools-3.30/lib/File/Spec.pm) to extract the filename and then replace it with whatever you want

Answer (score 10):

Regular expressions is the wrong tool for your problem. Regexes are fantastic, work most of the time but are not always the cleanest (readability) or fastest solution.

I would propose to use the classic [File::Basename](http://search.cpan.org/~nwclark/perl-5.8.9/lib/File/Basename.pm). In contrast with File::Spec, File::Basename is a core module (nothing to install!) and really easy to use:

```
    use File::Basename;

    my $basename = basename($fullname,@suffixlist);
    my $dirname  = dirname($fullname);
```

My favorite use:

```
    my $filename = basename($path);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my $string = "/dir/dir1/filename.txt";
my @string = split /\//, $string;
$string[-1] = "newfilename.txt";
print join "/", @string;
```